# How did I break git?

Tags: git, function, zsh

I thought I had copied the file path I wanted to check a git diff of, but accidentally had "`quit()`" in my clipboard instead and hastily hit return. So I accidentally ran

```
(base) user@MacBook-Air sage % git diff quit()
function> 
function>
```

and now, nothing seems to be working in git at all. For example:

```
(base) user@MacBook-Air sage % git diff HEAD
git:5: command not found: quit
(base) user@MacBook-Air sage % git status
git:6: command not found: quit
(base) user@MacBook-Air sage % git diff  
git:7: command not found: quit
(base) user@MacBook-Air sage % git log
git:8: command not found: quit
(base) user@MacBook-Air sage % git branch --list
git:9: command not found: quit
```

Does anyone know what I did to get this? Moreover, do you know how to fix it? All my changes on this branch are committed, but not yet on the remote branch.

I tried to Google how to reset git, but that just got me results for `git reset`.

Comment: Have you tried starting a new shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with git. Your shell thinks that you are starting to define a function after seing this `()`, and waits for the definition of the function body. And the `git` becomes the function name. After that when you call git, it runs the function you defined instead of real git.

Comment: Specifically, this is a zsh thing; bash would give a syntax error, but zsh defines two functions, `git` and `diff`.

Comment: @torek yes I later realized the same thing. It happens on zsh but not bash. Maybe it is a bug...

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. It's just the way function definition works in zsh - you can give several names to a function. But I must admit that I never used it: I usually give only a single name to my functions.